# Leaflet map on hide div

Tags: javascript, dictionary, hide, hidden, leaflet

I know there is some Topics about that but i still not manage it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var map = L.map('map',{
                center:[30.0,0.0],
                zoom: 2,
            });

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mboucas.ilm9bh3m/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '',
                maxZoom: 18
            }).addTo(map);

            var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

            var points_rand = L.geoJson(points, {
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer)
                {
                    var marker = L.marker(feature.geometry.coordinates);
                    markers.addLayer(marker);
                }   
            });

            map.addLayer(markers);

            map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());

            $("#map").hide();

            $("#buttonmap").click(function(){ 

                $("#map").slideDown();
                map.invalidateSize(false);
                map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());

            });

            $(".container").hover(function(){ 

            },function(){ 
                if($("#map").css("display")=="block") 
                { 
                    $("#map").slideUp(); 
                } 
            }); 
        });
```

I have tried everything

```
map.invalidateSize()
```

**and**

```
L.Util.requestAnimFrame(map.invalidateSize, map, false, map._container)
```

**and**

```
setTimeout(function(){ map.invalidateSize()}, 400)
```

nothing works.

Help me plz

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem, try this:

```
map._onResize();
```

This will force a resize of the map.

Comment: I have a bit change my code but it still the same problem.

i just don't whant to hide but reduce the height.

the map._onResize almost work but then the map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds()); didn't.

Comment: the fitbounds must detect the height on the css and not the actual one.